# Prove that determinant of the matrix is non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given a square matrix $A$ of order $2n$ such that $a_{ii}=0$ and $a_{ij}\in\{-1,1\},\space i\neq j$, prove that $\det(A)\neq0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\det A = \sum_{\sigma\in D_{2n}} (\pm 1)$, where the sum is over all fixed point free permutation $\sigma\in S_{2n}$ ("derangements"). So it suffices to show that the number $!(2n)$ of derangements of an even number of objects is odd. This follows from the recursion
$$
!k = (k-1)(!(k-1)+!(k-2))
$$
by induction; in fact, it's immediate from this that $!k$ alternates between even and odd values. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) for background.

Comment: Nice! D_{2n} in the first summation should be changed to S_{2n}, right?

Comment: No, $D_{2n}$ (= derangements on $2n$ objects, $\subsetneqq S_{2n}$) is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

a suitably-chosen cofactor expansion shows that if a single non-zero element changes sign then the odd-even parity of the determinant is unaltered.

consider a matrix $M=[m_{ij}]$ with zeroes on the diagonal, $1$ elsewhere.

in the determinant mod(2) terms cancel in pairs, except for the case of the "codiagonal" which contributes
$$
\prod_{j=1}^{2n}m_{j,2n+1-j} \equiv_2 1
$$